# CollectionViewHeader instead first item

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Can I somehow put collectionViewHeader on place of first item in collectionView, and shift all items to right for one item
[image: Like here].

So `+` is header and right is actually first item in collection(index 0). Is it possible? Can I somehow do this with custom `CollectionViewLayout`.

Now I'm doing it with 2 different `CollectionViewCell`, but since I want to use `DiffebleDataSource` and `FetchResultController`, and dynamical update cell, I can't use 2 different cells(or can?).